# wxpython : button covers all in the frame

Tags: python, wxpython

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        #super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 200))
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'wxButton', pos=(300, 150), size=(320, 250))
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button1', pos=(8, 8), size=(10, 20))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


    def button1Click(self,event):
        #self.button1.Hide()
        self.SetTitle("Button1 clicked")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Actually I am expecting the button1 on the frame to have a look like a button - a bit raised and be placed in center of frame - but it is just expanding to the full frame. Also text Button1 looks like a text which does not has a button look like feeling?

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: The reason the button expanded like that is because the button was the sole child of the frame. If there's only one widget in the frame, no matter what it is, it will take up all the available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems creating a panel (and setting the panel as the button parent) solves the problem (I've increased the button width so that you can see the text...)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'wxButton', pos=(300, 150), size=(320, 250))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.panel, id=-1, label='Button1', pos=(8, 8), size=(100, 20))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def button1Click(self,event):
        self.SetTitle("Button1 clicked")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example()
    app.MainLoop()
```